# how to deploy apps from xcode to device

Tags: c#, xcode, deployment, xamarin

I am newbie to Apple. I have read many articles and stackoverflow threads but I am very confused. I am developing with XCode and MonoTouch(Xamarin). I am doing the development with C Sharp. I have done an application and I want to install that app to my iPad. I am working on MAC by the way.

According to my readings, I need to have a Apple Developer ID, which costs 99 us dollar. Is there another way to deploy without paying?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to deploy the App on to your device you need development certificate (could be created using  Keychain Access) and development provisioning profile (which could only be created using Apple's Developer Account) . If you want to deploy your app on to device without these file you need to Jail Break your device but keep in mind that your device will be no more in Warrantee after you Jail break it.

Comment: so there is no way to do it without paying? I dont want to do the jailbreak thing

Answer (score 2):

Unless you jailbreak your iOS Device you'll need a Developer ID from Apple.